# Heroku Git - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, ssh, github, rsa

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

E:\Windows\system32>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: mymail@yahoo.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Found existing public key: E:/Users/Stewie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key E:/Users/Stewie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... failed
 !    Fingerprint already exists. Please use one SSH key per Heroku account

E:\Windows\system32>git clone git@heroku.com:sharp-winter-5732.git -o heroku
Cloning into 'sharp-winter-5732'...

 !  Your key with fingerprint f2:a2:f9:4a:c4:16:5b:f1:5a:21:cb:d8:c4:d2:18:ef is
 not authorized to access sharp-winter-5732.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

E:\Windows\system32>
```

Why i am keep having this error? What should i do? And don't give me a minus, because i already looked at

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

and gives me

```
E:\Windows\system32>git config --global user.name "Stewie"

E:\Windows\system32>git config --global user.email "mymail@yahoo.com"

E:\Windows\system32>git config --global credential.helper cache
warning: credential.helper has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change credential.helper.

E:\Windows\system32>git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'


E:\Windows\system32>git clone git@heroku.com:sharp-winter-5732.git -o heroku
Cloning into 'sharp-winter-5732'...

!  Your key with fingerprint f2:a2:f9:4a:c4:16:5b:f1:5a:21:cb:d8:c4:d2:18:ef is
not authorized to access sharp-winter-5732.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

E:\Windows\system32>
```

and i also tried

[GitHub: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617113/github-newbie-problems-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end)

i don,t know what to do ....

Comment: did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 31):

It seems a problem with your keys. Perhaps you need to upload your current key to he heroku

```
heroku keys:add
```

Details at "Managing Your SSH Keys": https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: omgg this worked!  thank you!  been trying to fix this for at least two hours.  i tried reinstalling git and heroku toolbelt and doing heroku login again...don't know why that couldn't have just worked.

Answer (score 2):

[Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end)

In this link, I had the same issue and the steps below worked for me:

```
    ->heroku login
       abc@gmail.com & password
    ->cd C:\Users\yourusername\.ssh
    ->ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa
```

If it asks for any passphrase don't use blank, fill with a passphrase but do not forget it.

```
    ->heroku keys:add "id_rsa.pub"
```

Change directory to workspace, then

```
    ->git clone git@heroku.com:stark-dawn-1234.git -o heroku
```

Use the passphrase that you set above.