# "Git Push Heroku Master" - Cannot login to heroku - Cloud9 IDE

Tags: git, heroku, cloud9-ide

Having troubles with heroku. This problem kind of came out of nowhere. I've been pushing updates for months without error and all of a sudden I'm having problems.

When I do Git Push Heroku Master (on C9) I get prompted to login:

```
> remote: !       WARNING: remote: !       Do not authenticate with
> username and password using git. remote: !       Run `heroku login` to
> update your credentials, then retry the git command.
```

However if I run "heroku login" I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:59:in `commands'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:208:in `find_command'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:12:in `try_takeover'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
/usr/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    Command:     heroku login
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.42.20 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.1


    More information in /home/ubuntu/.heroku/error.log
```

I've seen the advice to try the following but when I try I get the same error above:

```
username : blank

password : heroku auth token
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10873094/842935

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/672) & [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#troubleshooting).

In the C9 console run: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku`

Then run `heroku login`  and log back in. Good to go!

From Heroku docs:

> If you continue to have problems and the CLI is up to date, or if
>   updating fails for other reasons, you can reset the CLI by deleting
>   its user directories. These directories are replaced automatically and
>   you will not be logged out, but you will lose any installed plugins

Comment: Solved my heroku strange error on C9 after a bad loging