# GitHub with Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I don't really know what is happening, i had a key and the key work's for all the work with git, even in git bash i can push, pull, fetch and all other procedures, EXCEPT clone.

But, if i use powershell the clone just work's(but for real, powershell really have some issues).

When i try to clone with the git bash the error message is "Permission denied(public key)".

I don't believe that something is wrong with the public key, if it's wrong then i never be able to clone with this key...

Anyone know's what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [permission denied (publickey) Error using git on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127104/permission-denied-publickey-error-using-git-on-windows-7)

Comment: Actualy no... i made the path in this question before i write mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem and stop here I'm sorry but actually I never found the answer.

I just used the powershell back then, and some months after that I needed to clone the same repository and I used Git bash because it is easy and fast. I forgot of this issue with the tool and just works.

Maybe it is some cache/register/junk problem with Windows, if you are facing this, try to restart, or logoff or look at the processes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ssh keys on github.com See if you have more than one associated and possibly are not using the same one.

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/reviewing-your-ssh-keys

Comment: I will do this, again